# even entire function of exponential type and bounded on the real axis implies that it has infinite complex roots;

Tags: entire-functions

how can i prove that an even, entire function of exponential type, which is bounded on the real axis has an infinite number of complex roots (using Hadamard's theorem);
it must be straightforward but i am mission something.

thanx

Comment: what about $\sin(z)$ ?

Comment: you are right. obviously $sin(z)$ satisfies the conditions and has only real roots. my function also satisfies that $f(k)<0,\ \forall k\in \mathbb{R}-\{0\}$. So a better question is: any even, entire function of exponential type, bounded on the real line and strictly negative has infinite complex roots;